# Aws-chime-sdk demo lambda /join stops responding when attached to a VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

I have 2 lambdas that were created by a demo script of aws-chime-sdk. I have attached them to a vpc because I need them be able to access RDS and ElastiCache.

The first one have an api gateway resource to / which responds with the index content after doing some database/redis work. The problem is the second one that should respond for post requests at /join. When I attach it to same vpc, it stops to work and if I take it out, it works(even having same permissions/security groups of the other one) but don't give me access to rds/elasticache. I'm stuck on it. Does any one knows what is missing here?